# how to convert a string to list,say x='REGEX:/rest/ethernet-networks/\w{8}(-\w{4}){3}-\w{12}'

Tags: list, nested

I am splitting the string based on ':'. Post that, the second word I get is of string type, how do I make it of list type?
my code is

```
words=x.split(":")
```

`type(word[1])` gives str

I want it to be of type list.

How do I do that?

Comment: So what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I just split string by `:`and then get second item from the list. Now, the item is appending to the new created list:

```
In [1]: x='REGEX:/rest/ethernet-networks/\w{8}(-\w{4}){3}-\w{12}'
In [2]: j = []
In [3]: j.append(x.split(":")[1])
In [4]: j
Out[4]: ['/rest/ethernet-networks/\\w{8}(-\\w{4}){3}-\\w{12}']
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Comment: I just split string by ":" and then get second item from the list. Now, the item is appending to the new created list.

Comment: Rather than add relevant content as a comment, you should edit your answer to improve its quality. I've done this for you now - as an example.